# BroadcastReceiver in fragment doesn't work kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to make a bluetooth app, but have problem.
BroadcastReceiver always doesn't work in fragment.
And following code is second fragment in my app.
Bluetooth must be turned on in first fragment and then app can be able to jump to fragment two.

my code

```
class listFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var arrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireActivity().applicationContext, R.layout.device_name);
        val bluetoothManager : BluetoothManager? = requireActivity().applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager?
        val bluetooth = bluetoothManager!!.adapter

        val list: ListView = binding.blueDevices
        list.adapter = arrayAdapter
        activity?.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND))
        activity?.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED))

        val findBlueClick: Button = binding.button

        findBlueClick.setOnClickListener{
            if (bluetooth.isDiscovering) {
                bluetooth.cancelDiscovery()
            }else {
                bluetooth.startDiscovery()
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private val receiver =  object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action: String?  = intent.action
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
                val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                if (device != null && device.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    arrayAdapter?.add(device.name + "\n" + device.address)
                    Log.e("found","found")
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED == action) {
                if (arrayAdapter!!.count == 0) {
                    arrayAdapter?.add("noDevices")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        activity?.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        activity?.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        activity?.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND))
        activity?.registerReceiver(receiver,IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED))
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: use `registerReceiver` method once (in `onResume` prefferably) with multiple items in `IntentFilter` - don't register (and unregister) same `BroadcastReceiver` multiple times. also ensure you have all permissions granted

Comment: So I need more information about your issue, does it never work or sometimes work?